# How to remove or put a class to an element when I click on another?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I have a problem, when I click on the radiobutton of the day (for example, Monday), I get the section for that day (Monday), but when I click on the day (for example, Tuesday) the section for Tuesday appears Along with Monday's, what I need to do is that, when I click on Monday's radiobutton, they will look for Monday's section and that when I click on Tuesday's radiobutton, I will appear on Tuesday and remove Monday's, like this for each day of the week.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("input + label.Principal").forEach((e) => {
  const radio = e.parentNode.children[0];
  const dia = e.textContent.trim();
  radio.addEventListener("input", () => {
    document
      .getElementById("contenedor" + dia)
      .classList.add("contenedor" + dia + "Mostrar");
    console.log(dia);
  });
});
```

```css
#planActivate {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
}

.guia {
  padding: 200px;
}
.negrita {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.letra {
  font-size: 30px;
}
.botonIniciar {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
  background: rgb(29, 29, 73);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 15px;
}
.fecha {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.contadorSemana {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.semana {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 100px;
}
.Principal {
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 15px;
  border: solid 2px #012e58;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: #012e58;
}
.botonDia input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.botonDia input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background-color: #012e58;
  padding: 50px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: #fff;
}

.contenedorLunes {
  display: none;
}
.contenedorLunesMostrar {
  display: block;
}
.contenedorMartes {
  display: none;
}
.contenedorMartesMostrar {
  display: block;
}
.contenedorMiercoles {
  display: none;
}
.contenedorMiercolesMostrar {
  display: block;
}
.contenedorJueves {
  display: none;
}
.contenedorJuevesMostrar {
  display: block;
}
.contenedorViernes {
  display: none;
}
.contenedorViernesMostrar {
  display: block;
}
.contenedorSabado {
  display: none;
}
.contenedorSabadoMostrar {
  display: block;
}
.contenedorDomingo {
  display: none;
}
.contenedorDomingoMostrar {
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
}
.gridVideos {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
}
.video1,
.video2,
.video3 {
  text-align: center;
}
.video {
  padding: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="planActivate">
    <p>
      ¡Bienvenido a tu plan de actividad física! A través de este, tendrás diferentes guías para volver el ejercicio
      un hábito de vida a favor de tu salud y bienestar integral.
    </p>

    <p>Para empezar, es importante que puedas informarte sobre las siguientes recomendaciones mínimas para
      que tu paso del sedentarismo a la actividad física regular sea saludable y sin lesiones o contratiempos de
      ningún tipo.</p>

    <div class="guia">
      <p>espacio en blanco (falta información) </p>
    </div>

    <div class="Reto">
      <p> <span class="negrita letra">Reto 4 semanas</span> </p>
      <p>¡Es momento de empezar a activarte! En el siguiente reto, encontrarás una rutina de ejercicios diaria
        durante un mes para ponerte en sintonía con el cambio de hábitos que deseas y pasar del sedentarismo a
        la acción, con la guía de nuestros expertos.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="Iniciar">
      <p>Selecciona la fecha de inicio:</p>
      <input class="fecha" type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha">
      <a href="#" class="botonIniciar">Iniciar</a>
    </div>
    <div class="contadorSemana">
      <p class="negrita">Semana 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="semana">
      <div class="botonDia">
        <input name="dia" type="radio" id="lunes" />
        <label for="lunes" class="Principal">Lunes </label>
      </div>
      <div class="botonDia">
        <input name="dia" type="radio" id="martes" />
        <label for="martes" class="Principal">Martes </label>
      </div>
      <div class="botonDia">
        <input name="dia" type="radio" id="miercoles" />
        <label for="miercoles" class="Principal">Miercoles </label>
      </div>
      <div class="botonDia">
        <input name="dia" type="radio" id="jueves" />
        <label for="jueves" class="Principal">Jueves </label>
      </div>
      <div class="botonDia">
        <input name="dia" type="radio" id="viernes" />
        <label for="viernes" class="Principal">Viernes </label>
      </div>
      <div class="botonDia">
        <input name="dia" type="radio" id="sabado" />
        <label for="sabado" class="Principal">Sabado </label>
      </div>
      <div class="botonDia">
        <input name="dia" type="radio" id="domingo" />
        <label for="domingo" class="Principal">Domingo </label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="contenedorLunes" id="contenedorLunes">
      <div class="texto">
        <p>¡Feliz día! Para el entrenamiento de
          hoy vas a necesitar:</p>
        <ul>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="videos">
        <div class="gridVideos">
          <div class="video1">
            <p>Calentamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video2">
            <p>Entrenamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video3">
            <p>Estiramiento</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contenedorMartes" id="contenedorMartes">
      <div class="texto">
        <p>¡Feliz día! Para el entrenamiento de
          hoy vas a necesitar:</p>
        <ul>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="videos">
        <div class="gridVideos">
          <div class="video1">
            <p>Calentamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video2">
            <p>Entrenamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video3">
            <p>Estiramiento</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contenedorMiercoles" id="contenedorMiercoles">
      <div class="texto">
        <p>¡Feliz día! Para el entrenamiento de
          hoy vas a necesitar:</p>
        <ul>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="videos">
        <div class="gridVideos">
          <div class="video1">
            <p>Calentamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video2">
            <p>Entrenamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video3">
            <p>Estiramiento</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contenedorJueves" id="contenedorJueves">
      <div class="texto">
        <p>¡Feliz día! Para el entrenamiento de
          hoy vas a necesitar:</p>
        <ul>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="videos">
        <div class="gridVideos">
          <div class="video1">
            <p>Calentamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video2">
            <p>Entrenamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video3">
            <p>Estiramiento</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contenedorViernes" id="contenedorViernes">
      <div class="texto">
        <p>¡Feliz día! Para el entrenamiento de
          hoy vas a necesitar:</p>
        <ul>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="videos">
        <div class="gridVideos">
          <div class="video1">
            <p>Calentamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video2">
            <p>Entrenamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video3">
            <p>Estiramiento</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contenedorSabado" id="contenedorSabado">
      <div class="texto">
        <p>¡Feliz día! Para el entrenamiento de
          hoy vas a necesitar:</p>
        <ul>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="videos">
        <div class="gridVideos">
          <div class="video1">
            <p>Calentamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video2">
            <p>Entrenamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video3">
            <p>Estiramiento</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contenedorDomingo" id="contenedorDomingo">
      <div class="texto">
        <p>¡Feliz día! Para el entrenamiento de
          hoy vas a necesitar:</p>
        <ul>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="videos">
        <div class="gridVideos">
          <div class="video1">
            <p>Calentamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video2">
            <p>Entrenamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video3">
            <p>Estiramiento</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="resumen">

    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="js/Activate.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of 1 class for each day of the week, just have one class which starts off the element hidden and a single class which overrides this to visible.

Then its just a case of finding the currently shown and removing that class, then finding the right element and adding it (as you had, but without the day-specific class)

```
.contenedor { /* initial state of all content */
  display: none;
}
.show { /* state when you want it visible */
  display: block;
}
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll("input + label.Principal").forEach((e) => {
  const radio = e.parentNode.children[0];
  const dia = e.textContent.trim();
  radio.addEventListener("input", () => {
    document
      .querySelector(".show")
      ?.classList?.remove("show");
    document
      .getElementById("contenedor" + dia)
      .classList.add("show");
    console.log(dia);
  });
});
```

```css
#planActivate {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
}

.guia {
  padding: 200px;
}
.negrita {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.letra {
  font-size: 30px;
}
.botonIniciar {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
  background: rgb(29, 29, 73);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 15px;
}
.fecha {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.contadorSemana {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.semana {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 100px;
}
.Principal {
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 15px;
  border: solid 2px #012e58;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: #012e58;
}
.botonDia input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.botonDia input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background-color: #012e58;
  padding: 50px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: #fff;
}

.contenedor {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
.gridVideos {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
}
.video1,
.video2,
.video3 {
  text-align: center;
}
.video {
  padding: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="planActivate">
    

    <div class="Iniciar">
      <p>Selecciona la fecha de inicio:</p>
      <input class="fecha" type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha">
      <a href="#" class="botonIniciar">Iniciar</a>
    </div>
    <div class="contadorSemana">
      <p class="negrita">Semana 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="semana">
      <div class="botonDia">
        <input name="dia" type="radio" id="lunes" />
        <label for="lunes" class="Principal">Lunes </label>
      </div>
      <div class="botonDia">
        <input name="dia" type="radio" id="martes" />
        <label for="martes" class="Principal">Martes </label>
      </div>
      <div class="botonDia">
        <input name="dia" type="radio" id="miercoles" />
        <label for="miercoles" class="Principal">Miercoles </label>
      </div>
      <div class="botonDia">
        <input name="dia" type="radio" id="jueves" />
        <label for="jueves" class="Principal">Jueves </label>
      </div>
      <div class="botonDia">
        <input name="dia" type="radio" id="viernes" />
        <label for="viernes" class="Principal">Viernes </label>
      </div>
      <div class="botonDia">
        <input name="dia" type="radio" id="sabado" />
        <label for="sabado" class="Principal">Sabado </label>
      </div>
      <div class="botonDia">
        <input name="dia" type="radio" id="domingo" />
        <label for="domingo" class="Principal">Domingo </label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="contenedor" id="contenedorLunes">
      <div class="texto">
        <p>¡Feliz día! Para el entrenamiento de
          hoy vas a necesitar:</p>
        <ul>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="videos">
        <div class="gridVideos">
          <div class="video1">
            <p>Calentamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video2">
            <p>Entrenamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video3">
            <p>Estiramiento</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contenedor" id="contenedorMartes">
      <div class="texto">
        <p>¡Feliz día! Para el entrenamiento de
          hoy vas a necesitar:</p>
        <ul>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="videos">
        <div class="gridVideos">
          <div class="video1">
            <p>Calentamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video2">
            <p>Entrenamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video3">
            <p>Estiramiento</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contenedor" id="contenedorMiercoles">
      <div class="texto">
        <p>¡Feliz día! Para el entrenamiento de
          hoy vas a necesitar:</p>
        <ul>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="videos">
        <div class="gridVideos">
          <div class="video1">
            <p>Calentamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video2">
            <p>Entrenamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video3">
            <p>Estiramiento</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contenedor" id="contenedorJueves">
      <div class="texto">
        <p>¡Feliz día! Para el entrenamiento de
          hoy vas a necesitar:</p>
        <ul>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="videos">
        <div class="gridVideos">
          <div class="video1">
            <p>Calentamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video2">
            <p>Entrenamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video3">
            <p>Estiramiento</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contenedor" id="contenedorViernes">
      <div class="texto">
        <p>¡Feliz día! Para el entrenamiento de
          hoy vas a necesitar:</p>
        <ul>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="videos">
        <div class="gridVideos">
          <div class="video1">
            <p>Calentamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video2">
            <p>Entrenamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video3">
            <p>Estiramiento</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contenedor" id="contenedorSabado">
      <div class="texto">
        <p>¡Feliz día! Para el entrenamiento de
          hoy vas a necesitar:</p>
        <ul>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="videos">
        <div class="gridVideos">
          <div class="video1">
            <p>Calentamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video2">
            <p>Entrenamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video3">
            <p>Estiramiento</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contenedor" id="contenedorDomingo">
      <div class="texto">
        <p>¡Feliz día! Para el entrenamiento de
          hoy vas a necesitar:</p>
        <ul>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="videos">
        <div class="gridVideos">
          <div class="video1">
            <p>Calentamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video2">
            <p>Entrenamiendo</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="video3">
            <p>Estiramiento</p>
            <div class="video"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="resumen">

    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="js/Activate.js"></script>
```